# Long press quick settings tile in android (sdk >= 33) on lockscreen without unlocking

Tags: android, tiles

I want to show an overlay activity over the lock screen without needing to put my password when long pressing my app quick settings tile. Here is my code :

```
<activity
            android:name=".PopupActivity"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/TransparentDialogTheme"
            android:exported="true"
            android:showOnLockScreen="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE_PREFERENCES"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

It asks for the password when I long press the tile. Do you have any idea ?

Also I succedded to show my overlay over the lockscreen, but just can't launch it from the quicktiles.

If it's not possible I'll will have to look for the lockscreen bottom buttons widget as sdk 34 allows customizations but it will be great if I can keep sdk 33 support.

Thank you